# Configure Description field in Rally to be plain text

Tags: jira, rally, jira-plugin

I'm using the RallyConnectorforJira-Ruby-2.7.4 to sync issues between Rally and JIRA, but the description field in Rally is using HTML/Rich Text and inserting  tags into the description field in JIRA when it syncs. E.g.

```
<div>
</div>
<div>Updating the description to see if sync is working the other way.</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>Another update, this time changing state to Open in Rally, which should move the issue to In Progress in JIRA. Also, will the JIRALink field now get picked up?</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>Will it let me move this to re-opened?</div>
<div></div>
<div>Changed the workflow in JIRA to see if this breaks the integration - will it update, but error, or not update at all?</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>Fixing the workflow - this should move to In Progress</div>
```

JIRA is using the Default Text Renderer and according to the instructions at http://www.rallydev.com/help/jira-installation-user-guide *"you can elect to have the Description field in either system consist of just plain text, without any markup."*, but I can't find any instructions or settings in Rally that let me define the Description field as plain text in Rally.

If I log in to Rally and select Setup -> Workspaces -> Projects & Workspaces ->  -> Work Products and Fields -> Description -> Edit I see the following:

- Name: description
- Display Name: Description
- Type: Text
- Hidden: unchecked
- Occurrences: 20
- Required: unchecked

but no option to change the Type or specify plain text only.

Is it possible to set the Description field in Rally to be plain text only so that there is no HTML markup inserted into the field at source? Or is there something in jira_config.xml that I should be setting to tell it to remove HTML markup from the field coming across from Rally?

Thanks,

Andrew.

Comment: I would file a support case and we can help you through this.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I think my colleague has already raised a support ticket for this - Case #73689. Cheers, Andrew.

Comment: Any update to this item?  Running into the same problem.  Seems very basic but can't solve.